# Laravel certificate verification errors when sending TLS email

Tags: php, laravel, email, openssl

Windows 10, Apache httpd 2.4, PHP 7.1.4, Laravel 5.5
Gmail's less secure is Allowed.

---

My .env file:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=account@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

Error Message:

> Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com

---

```
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Error Message:

> stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1.
> OpenSSL Error messages:
> error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed

How can I resolve the "certificate verify failed" error?

Comment: If certificate verification failed for a prominent domain like smtp.gmail.com, I'd suspect that someone's hijacked your DNS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your operating system doesn't automatically manage your trusted certificate store:

1. Download [the cURL `cacert.pem` certificate bundle](https://curl.se/ca/cacert.pem)
2. Put the cacert.pem bundle somewhere you like; if you have self-signed certificates that need to be accepted, open the bundle in a text editor and add them to the end of the file.
3. Edit `php.ini` to reference this file location:

```
curl.cainfo = D:/Servers/php/sslfiles/cacert.pem
openssl.cafile = D:/Servers/php/sslfiles/cacert.pem
```

4. Restart PHP-FPM or your web server, depending on how you are running PHP.

Answer (score -1):

When you receive ssl certificate verification error, You can set these two variables in .env file:

```
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tcp
```

Comment: This doesn't explain the issue behind the original question and doesn't solve it. You're just telling how to disable a security feature to stop getting the error.