# Unable to connect to mail server from PHP on windows 10

Tags: php, laravel, ssl, windows-10

I am trying to configure my localhost Laravel project to be able to send an email, however, I am getting:

```
[2022-05-04 22:59:20] local.DEBUG: An error occurred while trying to create a user: adelin.ghanayem@gmail.com Swift_TransportException: Connection could not be established with host smtp.zoho.com :stream_socket_client(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed in C:\workspace\project\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\StreamBuffer.php:261
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Swift_Transport_StreamBuffer->{closure}()
```

PHP version is as below;

```
php -v
PHP 8.1.5 (cli) (built: Apr 12 2022 17:38:57) (ZTS Visual C++ 2019 x64)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.1.5, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v3.1.4, Copyright (c) 2002-2022, by Derick Rethans
```

**Note:

My time on the machine is correct!**

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mail.server.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=mail@mail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=SSL
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=mail@mail.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel certificate verification errors when sending TLS email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49303687/laravel-certificate-verification-errors-when-sending-tls-email)

Comment: @Justinas Nop I tried it It didn't work

Comment: Show us how you tried to add it